# Dimensions of Lie algebra powers of irreducible representations

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras

Consider the following plethysms. For semisimple Lie algebras $L$, if $A$ is the adjoint irrep, as far as I know, the dimensions are as follows: $d_1=|A^{\bigotimes 1}|=0$ (meaning e.g. no lollipops O- i.e. trace over structure constant tensor Y is zero), $d_2=|A^{\bigotimes 2}|=1$ (Schur's Lemma), $d_3=|A^{\bigotimes 3}|=1$ (structure constant tensor is the only invariant, 6j symbols).
And if $A$ is the adjoint of a non-semisimple $L$? I also read something like that the Killing form $K$ can be brought to $\mathrm{diag}(\{0,1\})$ in the right basis, implying $K^2=K$ and thus $d_2=2$ (unless $L$ is nilpotent, $K=0$ and thus $d_2=1$). But I'm confused - rescale the basis and the Killing form might have more than two different eigenvalues for more than 4 generators? (Does it?)
Assuming it miraculously hasn't, this means $d_3\leq 8$ (one or no Killing form pasted on the structure constant tensor). I already once jumped to conclusions :-) and thought $d_3=1$, but I found a $L$ with $d_3=4$. So, can you name a $L$ with $d_3=8$?.
(In graphic form the answers to my question seem obvious :-) - you add a bivalent node, i.e. the Killing form, to the trivalent node formalism, and everything else follows from graphic manipulations. But of course I always assume that this is legit and have no formal proof...)

Comment: Please could you define your notation more clearly. What are $d_1$, $d_2$, $\ldots$? What is a lollipop in this context? What is meant by your final parenthetical comment?

Comment: The adjoint representation of a Lie algebra is irreducible iff the algebra is *simple* (rather than semisimple). Thus for example $d_2=k$ for a direct sum of $k$ non-abelian simple Lie algebras. Similar remarks apply to direct sums in general, so that there can be no upper estimates on any of these invariants without imposing extra assumptions.